# Special characters (braces) get unwanted backslash using collapse_rows()

Tags: kableextra

When creating a table with kable and kableExtra in a R markdown program, I want to group rows and generate a group header using the collapse_rows() function. This works fine. However, if the values in the variable used for grouping contain special characters, such as "(" and ")", the rendered pdf has inserted "\" in front of the special characters in the header line.
Is there any way how to fix this?

I am running R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) -- "Kite-Eating Tree" on
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit).
R Studio is version 1.1.442.
Knitr is version 1.18.
KableExtra is version 0.9.0.
latex-engine is defaulted to pdflatex, but I also tried xelatex.

I also tried setting escape=T in kable() as well as column_spec(), the first has no effect and the second causes an error message in my environment.

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
  fig_caption: yes
documentclass: article
fontsize: 11pt
geometry: "a4paper, portrait, left=3.00cm, right=1.98cm, bottom=3.81cm, top=2.01cm"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r prepcode, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, include=FALSE}
rm(list=ls())
library(tidyverse)
options(kableExtra.latex.load_packages = FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r tab, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
x <- rnorm(n=18)
t <- expand.grid(COL1=c("Stratum 1 (my first stratum)", "Stratum 2 (my second stratum)"),
                 COL2=c("A", "B", "C"),
                 COL3=c("x", "y", "z"))
xt <- cbind(t, COL4=x) %>% arrange(COL1, COL2, COL3)

knitr::kable(xt, format="latex", row.names=FALSE, booktabs=T) %>%
  kable_styling(font_size=8, latex_options = c("repeat_header")) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold=T) %>%
  collapse_rows(1:2, row_group_label_position = 'stack', latex_hline = "major")
```
````

For example, "Stratum 1 (my first stratum)" is displayed as "Stratum 1 \(my first stratum\)" in the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent kableExtra from escaping special characters in stacked rows by changing the `collapse_rows` call to

```
collapse_rows(1:2, row_group_label_position = 'stack', latex_hline = "major", 
              row_group_label_fonts = list (list (escape = FALSE)))
```